# How can i have delete and edit link in django admin change list page

Tags: python, django

I am using django admin.

But there are currenly no delete links infront of every row. they have delete selected thing  but i want to have delete and edit with every row of model.

how can i do that in django admin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class MyAdmin(models.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('other_field', 'delete_link', 'edit_link')


    def delete_link(self, obj):
        info = obj._meta.app_label, obj._meta.module_name
        url = reverse('admin:%s_%s_delete' % info, args=(obj.id,))
        return '<a href="%s">Delete</a>' % url
    delete_link.allow_tags = True
    delete_link.short_description = 'Delete'

    def edit_link(self,obj):
        return u'<a href="/admin/%s/%s/%s">Edit</a>' % (
             obj._meta.app_label, obj._meta.module_name, obj.id)
    edit_link.allow_tags = True
    edit_link.short_description = "Edit"
```

**UPDATE:**

```
def action_link(self, obj):
    app_name = obj._meta.app_label
    url_name = obj._meta.module_name
    data_id = obj.id

    return """
         <ul>
            <li><a href="/admin/{0}/{1}/{2}">Edit</a></li>
            <li><a href="/admin/{0}/{1}/{2}/delete">Delete</a></li>
         </ul>
         """.format(
         obj._meta.app_label, 
         obj._meta.module_name, 
         obj.id)
action_link.allow_tags = True
action_link.short_description = 'Actions'
```

Comment: wow , that worked perfectly. thank you very much for that, i am sorry i can't upvote because of less points. Can you tell me how can i put delete , edit in one tag like `<ul>` because i want to use bootsrap icons in one table cell fr edit delete

Comment: That's ok, hmmmmm... I don't know but give me time to think about your problem

Comment: I think you can modify my codes in one function only so that you can add that <ul>, I will try to test it in my app

Answer (score 0):

Fields can be made editable inline within Django admin using the `list_editable` admin option: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_editable

However, there's no built-in option to add a delete link to every row. That's something you would need to add yourself. You would need to use a combination of a property on the model to add to the `list_display` in order to get the 'Delete' text in the change list, plus some JavaScript to confirm the delete. I wouldn't fire the delete in a single action.

It's up to you whether you want to fire the delete action via Ajax, or if you want to redirect them to the delete view, etc. Hope that gets you started.